# v3 IPP FindAll is not returing the correct paged data when Customers are sub-customers

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I'm using the below line:

commonService.FindAll(new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Customer(), currentPage, itemListPageSize).ToList();

When returning multiple pages the paging isn't returning the right rows on page if there are sub-customers. To reproduce, just create several customers and retrieve the second page like:

commonService.FindAll(new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Customer(), 2, itemListPageSize).ToList();

When it retrieves page 2, the first page's data is returned.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

FindAll with paging actually uses query endpoint. 
Please mention if you are trying this call against QBD/QBO.

Can you please capture the raw request and response of the above call and share in this post. 
(for that you can enable logger as mentioned in the following docs, or you can configure your app with any http snooper like Fiddler.)

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0150_ipp_.net_devkit_3.0/logging

You can try this call directly using ApiExplorer. Please verify if you are getting the same result. 
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/020_key_concepts/00300_query_operations/0100_key_topics#Pagination

Thanks